# List assignment index out of range error

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a simple array program and print out the array elements but getting an error right after I input employee 2 value saying: IndexError: list assignment index out of range.

```
#Create constant for the number of employees.
SIZE = 3

#Create an array to hol the number of hours worked by each employee.
hours = [SIZE]

#Get the hours worked by employee 1.
hours[0] = int(input("Enter the hours worked by employee 1: "))

#Get the hours worked by employee 2.
hours[1] = int(input("Enter the hours worked by employee 2: "))

#Get the hours worked by employee 3.
hours[2] = int(input("Enter the hours worked by employee 3: "))

#Display the values entered.
print("The hours you entered are:")
print(hours[0])
print(hours[1])
print(hours[2])
```

Comment: you're not setting any size with `hours = [SIZE]`, your list has only one index

Comment: `[SIZE]` is a 1-element list whose only element is the number 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't have literal arrays: it has lists. `hours = [SIZE]` doesn't create a list with 3 elements: it creates a list with 1 element. You should use `append()` to add items to a list, not indexing past the end of the array.

The correct code would look something like this to add elements to the list:

```
hours.append(int(input("Enter the hours worked by employee 1: ")))
hours.append(int(input("Enter the hours worked by employee 2: ")))
hours.append(int(input("Enter the hours worked by employee 3: ")))
```

From the comments, it seems you're learning code from a pseudocode textbook: that's wonderful. Just remember though that certain conventions common to pseudocode, or sometimes C-like languages may be different in other programming languages. For example, in C, this declares an array of 50 chars named `x`.

```
char x[50];
```

In Python, you cannot use the same syntax. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning programming logic and they use pseudocode which I'm trying to translate over to python code as I go.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I know, also, NumPy is literally based on them. But not literal arrays. I should probably mention that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the wrong idea on how arrays work in Python. Essentially what you're doing when you typed

```
#Create constant for the number of employees.
SIZE = 3

#Create an array to hol the number of hours worked by each employee.
hours = [SIZE]
```

Is create an array with **one** element with a value of 3

```
hours = [3]
```